# How to cache a WSDL with Java-WS

Tags: java, netbeans, wsdl, java-ws

I've created an app that interacts with a SOAP service using java WS.  I generate classes and manage the WSDL using the built in netbeans functions.

Every time I run the application, it has to download the WSDL and parse it again.  The WSDL is frozen at each version so I don't think this is necessary.  I've tried to reference it as a local file, but then my app complains it can't find the file when it's installed on another machine.

Does anyone know how I can stop Java WS needing to re-parse the WSDL, or at least cache it locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out...

This page has the info

[Developing client application with locally packaged WSDL](https://javaee.github.io/metro/doc/user-guide/ch02.html#developing-client-application-with-locally-packaged-wsdl)

Comment: Hi Cogsy,

Which of the solutions you ended up implementing?