# How to cache JAX-WS stub/port in Java?

Tags: caching, jax-ws

The use case is that the application (running on JBoss 5) must operate on very limited bandwidth. Currently every time we go to make a webservice call we request the wsdl and recreate the stub using [JAX-WS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/). Each time the stub is created the wsdl and schema is redownloaded. Idealy the wsdl would never be downloaded since we already have a copy of the schema, but even caching would work. Bonus points if the cache is Serializable!

**Is it possible to cache a JAX-WS stub/port?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best answer found so far:

**Tell the service to look at a local wsdl:**
[JAX-WS client : what's the correct path to access the local WSDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163586/jax-ws-client-whats-the-correct-path-to-access-the-local-wsdl/4178783#4178783)

**Change the endpoint on the fly:**
[JAX-WS Loading WSDL from jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764772/jax-ws-loading-wsdl-from-jar)

---

I don't see a way to cache, but using a local copy can be done as specified on this page on metro: [Developing client application with locally packaged WSDL](http://metro.java.net/2.1.1/guide/Developing_client_application_with_locally_packaged_WSDL.html)

(found on SO question : [How to cache a WSDL with Java-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456865/how-to-cache-a-wsdl-with-java-ws/464926#464926))

Answer (score 2):

I think we can cache stub using org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObject lirbrary.

Please see the below link for the same.

https://github.com/vikashnitk50/fasypay-webservice-client/tree/master/fasypay-webservice-client/src/main/java/com/fastpay/webservice/client